# Get html content as string format with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML and XSL like this:

**XML**

```
<definitions>
  <process id="Process_1">
    <Task id="Task_1yh7nak" name="Add">
      <Steps>
        <Step id="Step_1" Order="1">
          <Form>
            <form-template>
              <fields>
                <field type="text" label="start" id="text-14708410685"></field>
                <field type="text" label="end"  id="text-5651568987"></field>
                <field type="button" subtype="button" label="Button" id="button-1470841070721"></field>
              </fields>
            </form-template>
          </Form>
        </Step>        
      </Steps>
    </Task>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                              
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method = "text" omit-xml-declaration = "no" indent = "no" encoding="Windows-1252"/> 

 <!-- Start the code generation here. -->
  <xsl:template match ="*">

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Core
{
  public static class DynamicCode
  {
  <xsl:for-each select="/definitions/process/Task">
    public static string <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>_GetStartForm()
    {
     string formContent = "<xsl:for-each select="Steps/Step[@Order='1']/Form/form-template/fields/field">
      <!--Switch Case for type of controls -->
      <xsl:choose>          
        <xsl:when test="@type='text'">
          <h2> textbox </h2>
          <input>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </input>
          <br/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="@type='button'">
          <h2> button </h2>
          <input type="button">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </input>
          <br/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:for-each>";
     return formContent;
    }   
   </xsl:for-each>
  }
}

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I transform XML with this XSL (XSLT 1.0).

**Output**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Core
{
  public static class DynamicCode
  {

    public static string Task_1yh7nak_GetStartForm()
    {
     string formContent = " textbox  textbox  button ";
     return formContent;
    }   

  }
}
```

Online output:http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUY/1

I try to get full html content in `fields` tag as string format.  I need to this content for fill `Literal` in web page.

```
<h2> textbox </h2>
<input id="text-14708410685" value="start"></input>
<h2> textbox </h2>
<input id="text-5651568987" value="end"></input>
<h2> button </h2>
<input type="button" id="button-1470841070721" value="submit"></input>
```

But in output, I have only value of `h2` tag.

```
string formContent = " textbox  textbox  button ";
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Comment: If you want your elements like the `input` elements to show up then you need to use the `xsl:output method="html"` or `xml`, the text output method you use is supposed to output the plain text in text nodes, but not any markup of element nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thx,I didn't notice to it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen One question, The output should be a C# class but attributes have `"`. In string, it makes error. I can't use \ before and after them in `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: I understand the problem but I don't think there is an easy way around it in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. In XSLT 3.0 I would probably use literal result elements to construct the HTML elements in a variable, the use the `serialize` function to serialize and then finally use `replace` to make sure any quotes `"` are escaped as `\"` for the C# string literal.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can I get `xsl:value-of` without double quotes?

Comment: It is not the `value-of` that creates the nested, unescaped quotes, you are outputting literal text with double quotes and the serialization of result elements with attributes, and these are serialized with double quotes. As said, there is no easy and nice way out, unless you can use XSLT 3.0. Or you go the way proposed by Tim in his answer where you use output method `text` and then write code to construct the HTML markup with all necessary escaping of quotes done by hand to allow you to include the HTML markup inside of a C# string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that pleasant to look at, but in XSLT 1.0 you will have to manually escape all the HTML tags you wish to output.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                              
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method = "text" omit-xml-declaration = "no" indent = "no" encoding="Windows-1252"/> 

 <!-- Start the code generation here. -->
  <xsl:template match ="*">
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Core
{
  public static class DynamicCode
  {
  <xsl:for-each select="/definitions/process/Task">
    public static string <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>_GetStartForm()
    {
     string formContent = "<xsl:for-each select="Steps/Step[@Order='1']/Form/form-template/fields/field">
      <!--Switch Case for type of controls -->
      <xsl:choose>          
        <xsl:when test="@type='text'">
          <xsl:text>&lt;h2&gt;textbox&lt;/h2&gt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:text>&lt;input</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='button'">
          <xsl:text>&lt;h2&gt;button&lt;/h2&gt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:text>&lt;input type=\"button\"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text> id=\"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text> value=\"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@label" />
      <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&gt;&lt;/input&gt;</xsl:text>

  </xsl:for-each>";
     return formContent;
    }   
   </xsl:for-each>
  }
}

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the relevant line as follows:

```
 string formContent = "<h2>textbox</h2><input id=\"text-14708410685\" value=\"start\"></input><h2>textbox</h2><input id=\"text-5651568987\" value=\"end\"></input><h2>button</h2><input type=\"button\" id=\"button-1470841070721\" value=\"Button\"></input>";
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuH